# how to use Or criteria with list of Restrictions

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

so i have a list of Restrictions.eq that i want to add it to Restrictions.or criteria. is it even possible ? how ?
bellow is the example of what i have in my mind :

```
List<Integer> stars=Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
```

these are my Hotel rows in postgresql db :

1. id : 1 , name : Hilton Dubai , star : 1
2. id : 2 , name : Hilton Istanbul , star : 2
3. id : 3 , name : Hilton Paris , star : 3
4. id : 4 , name : Hilton London , star : 4
5. id : 5 , name : Hilton Rome , star : 5

   ```
   Criteria criteria = createCriteria();

   List<SimpleExpression> expressions=new ArrayList();
   for(Integer star:stars){
       expressions.add(Restrictions.eq("star",star));
   }

   criteria.add(Restrictions.or(expressions));

   List<Hotel> hotels=criteria.list(); // returns id 1 and 2 and 3
   ```

Comment: Yes, since or() expects a vararg (i.e. an array): http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#or-org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion...-. You can also use a disjunction and add your criteria: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#disjunction--. But unless you're maintaining a very old hibernate application (which I doubt: otherwise you would already have met this kind of code before), why are you using the old hibernate criteria API, that is deprecated, and will disappear in the next version?

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is incorrect. You are saying that take this all expressions or i will give you another expression when i give that concat them with an "or" check. 
You need to create expressions as a just one expression and add all simpleExpression to other expression with `Restrictions.or`.
Delete the `List<SimpleExpression> expressions=new ArrayList();`
Create A `Criterion`. 
Concat all `Criterion` with `Restrictions.or` in for loop..